# How to assign right-alt key to simulate right mouse button

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I never use the <kbd>Right-Alt</kbd> key. But I need a button that does the same as pressing the right-mouse button.

1. How to change the function of the right-alt button?
2. How to assign the function of the right mouse button?

[This](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=25142) is only about Photoshop in Linux.
[Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/assign-shortcut-keys-to-your-favorite-word-features-HA001042965.aspx) can only assign keys to existing actions.

The point of this is to edit merge fields without using the mouse.

Comment: I found a way to get the context-menu: Shift + F10 http://windowsitpro.com/windows/how-can-i-show-context-menu-without-right-mouse-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a tiny AutoHotKey script to remap <kbd>Right-Alt</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

```
*RAlt::Send +{F10}
```

Copy the code to a new text file and save it as *something.ahk*. Convert the script to an executable with *Ahk2Exe.exe* which is shipped together with the [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) installer.

#### Some unnecessary explanations

1. The script (.exe) will reside in your windows tray and wait for a trigger action.
   Pressing the key `*RAlt` is the trigger
2. `::` stands for assigning a function to the trigger
3. The called `send` function is for simulating a `+{F10}` key press.
   The preceding `+` sign stands for the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier and {F10} of course for the <kbd>F10</kbd> key

#### Find more details on AutoHotKey help pages

- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm
- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm
- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Comment: First, I tried [SharpKeys](http://stackoverflow.com/a/460800/935614) which is a GUI for remapping keys via registry. But I haven't found out how to map key combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the context-menu: Shift + F10 http://windowsitpro.com/windows/how-can-i-show-context-menu-without-right-mouse-button

Still using the right-Alt would be better, the real solution probably lies somewhere in Windows, if someone can answer point 1 or 2, I will accept that answer.